# How to use all rows from outside table as parameter for stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, parameter-passing

I want to use all the rows from a table in a stored procedure. Let's call that table2, or alias b.

The procedure I have currently is basically setting values depending on a where condition of a field.

```
UPDATE table1
SET a.Name = "VALID" 
FROM table1 a
WHERE a.Quality = 0
```

I want the `WHERE a.Quality = 0` clause to basically say "where a.Quality matches any number from table2 b"

How do I do this? Would it be a matter of passing the rows from the table2 as a parameter? Or can I solely use the where clause?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about using a simple `INNER JOIN`?

Like this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET a.Name = "VALID" 
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.Quality = b.SomeColumnNameHere
```

If you insist on using "only" the `WHERE` clause, you could try something like this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET a.Name = "VALID" 
FROM table1 a
WHERE a.Quality IN (SELECT SomeColumnNameHere
                    FROM table2)
```